# Clear ViewModel validation Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have created a **ViewModel** which contains other models

```
namespace CreatingLayout.Models
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public tbl_Roles Roles { get; set; }
        public tbl_Category Category { get; set; }
        public tbl_Course Course { get; set; }
        public tbl_User User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this sub Model has some Required Field field like **tbl_User** class has following required fields:

```
public partial class tbl_User
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter {0}")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter {0}")]
    public string Password{ get; set; }
    //And many more with Required Field
}
```

Now my problem is, in my View i am not passing data for all this required fields but only for few. So once i click to submit button, i am calling my Controller Action Method and i am checking for ModelState errors

```
public ActionResult AdminInsertion(ViewModel objViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //IF No Errors do something
    }
    return View();
}
```

So everytime my Modelstate.Isvalid is returning false due to Validation Error which i gave in those 4 classes i.e., tbl_Roles, tbl_Category, tbl_Course and tbl_User. So what i want is to Clear all those error for which i am not passing Data, something like

```
//Here i want to go to individual classes ex: item should contains all tbl_Roles column fields
foreach(var item in ModelState.Keys)
{
    //Now i want to Get Key items of each individual class which is causing Error 
    foreach(string Key in item)
    {
         //Here i am going to clear all those error for which i am not passing data
         ModelState[Key].Error.Clear();
    }
}
```

But my problem is, i am not able to access fields of tbl_Roles, tbl_Category, tbl_Course and tbl_User. ,How can clear only selected field errors here?

Comment: As always,create a view model containing only those properties your need to display/edit in the view.

Comment: But i don't want to keep creating new ViewModel everytime. There is no convenient way of clearing unwanted Errors via code something like the code i wrote in ending.

Comment: If if you clear ModelState error, that not going to stop a malicious user posting back values for other fields and causing your app to fail anyway. Use a view model.

Comment: No solution to solve it. Just for my Curiosity!

Comment: Yes, but I don't give bad advice :)